# ELKI - k-means clustering.

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means, elki

I' like to run ELKI k-means clustering in command line.

It seems that running time is too short compared with R programming. I tried to run k-means clustering in R, then It took about 100 seconds.
Moreover, there is no change among k=5, k=10 and so on.

`file.tsv` has 60,000 rows and 25 columns.

```
START=$(date +%s)
k=5
java -jar elki.jar KDDCLIApplication \
     -dbc.in "file.tsv" \
         -dbc.parser NumberVectorLabelParser \
         -parser.colsep "\t" \
     -algorithm clustering.kmeans.KMeansLloyd \
         -kmeans.k $k \
         -kmeans.initialization KMeansPlusPlusInitialMeans \
         -kmeans.maxiter 9999 \
     -resulthandler ResultWriter -out.gzip false \
         -out output/k-$k \

END=$(date +%s)
DIFF=$(( $END - $START ))
echo "It took $DIFF seconds"
```

The output is `"It took 5 seconds"`

```
START=$(date +%s)
k=10
java -jar elki.jar ...
     ...

END=$(date +%s)
DIFF=$(( $END - $START ))
echo "It took $DIFF seconds"
```

This case `k=10` is also `"It took 5 seconds"`.

Why is there no change among cluster sizes? Does the code have some problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 seconds is probably too fast to get you a reliable measurement.

Furthermore, with a larger `k` the result may converge with fewer iterations.

You may want to use `-time` to see the time needed to run the actual algorithm. With your method, *parsing* and *writing* will have a non-neglible impact. `-resulthandler DiscardResultHandler` will disable output, which is also reasonable for benchmarking.

You don't need to set `-kmeans.maxiter 9999`. By default, ELKI will run k-means until convergence.

I believe there was an implementation weakness in k-Means++ initialization that made it more costly than necessary. Maybe initialization, parsing, writing, contributes a lot to your total runtime.

Also try using `-resulthandler LogResultStructureResultHandler -verbose` to make sure the parser understood the file as intended (check the dimensionality!) With `-verbose` you can also check that it does a reasonable number of iterations.

Comment: I got 400[ms] in k=5, 800[ms] in k=10. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also try simpler initializations - using the much more naive `RandomlyChosenInitialMeans` should usually be slower. If I'm not mistaken, this is the default in R as well.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried `flexclust` library that has both random-initialization and k-means++. In any case, ELKI is incomparably faster than R implementation.

Comment: `flexclust` seems to be implemented in R, and was much slower than the native version in my experiments. R native (which is C code) was as fast as ELKI in my benchmarks (using default initialization), `flexclust` over 2 times slower. But ELKI is well optimized. In a number of cases I have had Hotspot dump the assembler code, and it does some pretty neat optimizations not possible in C (unrolling loops for the dimensionality of the data set). But the difference should not be this massive. Can you benchmark the R kmeans call alone, excluding startup and loading time?